# Ка привязать динамическое меню к базе данных?

Tags: jquery, php, javascript, mysql

Есть динамическое меню

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Gorizontal dropdown menu with jQuery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/jqueryslidemenu.css" />

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style type="text/css">
html .jqueryslidemenu{height: 1%;} /*Holly Hack for IE7 and below*/
</style>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jqueryslidemenu.js"></script>

</head>
<div id="myslidemenu" class="jqueryslidemenu">

<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com">Item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folder 1</a>    
  <ul>    
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.3</a></li>

  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 1.4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Folder 2</a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Folder 2.1</a>

    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Folder 3.1.1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Item 3.1.1.5</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sub Item 2.1.4</a></li>
    </ul>

  </li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
<br style="clear: left" />
</div>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Проще взглянуть на него тут: http://grimon.net/test_menu.php#
Как привязать его к БД? С возможностью добавления/удаления элементов?

Answer (score 1):

Таблицу лучше строить так.

id, pid, name, note

где

- id - идентифиактор строки
- pid - идентификатор родительской категории
- name - название категории
- note - описание

По умолчанию pid ставить 0, таковые будут родительсикими категориями... а все остальные с pid <> 0 будут подкатегориями.

Answer (score 0):

1. Создайте таблицу к примеру menu (id, menunum - пункты, type - к чему привязано, subnum - подпункты, name - имя, numric - порядок).
2. Составить в скрипте запрос к базе
3. Вывести результат

Comment: Это вся я и сам понял, но что же делать с CSS?

Answer (score 0):

присоединюсь к предыдущим ораторам - без БД тут не обойтись!  Создаешь БД, как говорили выше, потом отдельно пишешь еще один php-файл который будет управлять (добавлять/удалять/редактировать) нужные пункты меню.   а вывод уже самого меню, я обычно делаю на рекурсии, а потом стилями ему внешний вид навожу, ну и для красивости можно jquery подключить...